# Curves in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with given properties

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, problem-solving, curves, curvature

Question: Find two curves $α$ and $β$ such that $α(0) = β(0) = (1, 0, 0)$, both with
the same Frenet frame at $t = 0$ given by $T_α(0) = T_β(0) = (0, 1, 0)$, $N_α(0) = N_β(0) =
(−1, 0, 0)$, $B_α(0) = B_β(0) = (0, 0, 1)$, and moreover, $κ_α(0) = κ_β(0)$, but $τ_α(0) =
−τ_β(0) \neq 0$.

Okay, so I have found two curves given by $\alpha (t)=(1-\frac{t^2}{2}, t, \frac{t^3}{3})$ and $\beta (t)=(1-\frac{t^2}{2}, t, -\frac{t^3}{3})$. This seems to work. However, I am required to furnish unit-speed curves and it is difficult to give unit-speed parametrizations for my curves. Their speed is $\sqrt{t^4+t^2+1}$, which is creating difficulty.

I was wondering if we could use helices, but I'm not exactly able to understand how (the standard helix doesn't work). Please give me hints using a helix or otherwise, to get unit-speed curves for this problem.

Comment: Do you need to work out an explicit formula for the unit-length parametrization of your curves? Because if not, you can just use the fact that, if $\alpha$ is an arbitrary regular curve, and $l(t)$ gives its length "up to $t$", then the re-parametrization $\alpha \circ l^{-1}$ has unit-length. I know this sounds a bit lazy, but if you don't need to go into too many details, that does the work ^^ (or you could explicitly compute $l(t)$ and then plug it back in but that's probably not worth the trouble)

Comment: What's a Frenet frame?

Comment: @zhw. For a regular curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$, a Frenet frame gives an orthonormal basis at each point of the curve. It consists of three vector fields, namely, the tangent, principal normal and binormal vector fields. These determine the curvature and torsion of a curve. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas

Comment: @Nala I thought of doing the same like you have suggested. Because computing $l(t)$ is not easy for my curves. So I was wondering if we could come up with unit-speed curves satisfying all the given properties in the first place itself? Like, from scratch.

Comment: So what happens if you turn a right-handed helix into a left-handed helix?

Comment: @TedShifrin The torsion will change signs? But I don't know how to write those curves explicitly so that they satisfy all the required properties.

Comment: Start with the (arclength, if you insist) parametrization of a helix. What simple change reverses the handedness?

Comment: @TedShifrin Taking the negative of the $z$-coordinate?

Comment: Sounds good to me !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112688/discussion-between-whysee-and-ted-shifrin).

Comment: @TedShifrin I have written down an answer below. Can you have a look at it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured out a solution while having a discussion in the comments with Ted Shifrin. Thanks, Ted!

Let us consider the curves $\alpha (t)=(3\cos(\frac{t}{5}), 3\sin(\frac{t}{5}), \frac{4}{5}t)$ and $\beta (t)=(3\cos(\frac{t}{5}), 3\sin(\frac{t}{5}), -\frac{4}{5}t)$. Some data can be computed for these two curves:

$\alpha(0)=(3,0,0), T_\alpha(0)=(0,\frac{3}{5},\frac{4}{5}), N_\alpha(0)=(-1,0,0), B_\alpha(0)=(0,-\frac{4}{5},\frac{3}{5}), \kappa_\alpha=\frac{3}{25}, \tau_\alpha=\frac{4}{25}$.

Similarly,

$\beta(0)=(3,0,0), T_\beta(0)=(0,\frac{3}{5},-\frac{4}{5}), N_\beta(0)=(-1,0,0), B_\beta(0)=(0,\frac{4}{5},\frac{3}{5}), \kappa_\beta=\frac{3}{25}, \tau_\beta=-\frac{4}{25}$.

So, we have something ''like" what we want, but we have a little more work to do. We know that applying an isometry of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (with proper handedness concerns) to a regular curve gives a congruent curve, i.e, it preserves the curvature $\kappa$ and torsion $\tau$. I'll do it for $\alpha$ and it can be done similarly for $\beta$.

Let us call the isometry as $F$ such that $\overline\alpha=F\circ\alpha$ is the curve with the required properties, i.e, $\overline\alpha(0)=(1,0,0), T_\overline\alpha(0)=(0,1,0), N_\overline\alpha(0)=(-1,0,0), B_\overline\alpha(0)=(0,0,1), \kappa_\overline\alpha=\frac{3}{25}, \tau_\overline\alpha=\frac{4}{25}$. Now, as any isometry of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is composed of a translation and an orthogonal transformation, we can write $F(x)=Ax+a$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$ where $A$ is an orthogonal matrix and $a\in\mathbb{R}^3$ is a constant. It can also be shown that the transformation $A$ is the one which satisfies $A.T_\alpha(0)=T_\overline\alpha(0), A.N_\alpha(0)=N_\overline\alpha(0), A.B_\alpha(0)=B_\overline\alpha(0)$ and $a=\overline\alpha(0)-A.\alpha(0)$.

Doing these computations, we find that $A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{3}{5} & \frac{4}{5} \\ 0 & -\frac{4}{5} & \frac{3}{5} \end{pmatrix}$ and $a=(-2,0,0)$.

Therefore,

$\overline\alpha(t)=(3\cos(\frac{t}{5})-2, \frac{9}{5}\sin(\frac{t}{5})+\frac{16}{25}t, -\frac{12}{5}\sin(\frac{t}{5})+\frac{12}{25}t)$.

Proceeding in a similar fashion as above, we can find $\overline\beta$. It turns out that,

$\overline\beta(t)=(3\cos(\frac{t}{5})-2, \frac{9}{5}\sin(\frac{t}{5})+\frac{16}{25}t, \frac{12}{5}\sin(\frac{t}{5})-\frac{12}{25}t)$.

It can be verified that $\overline\alpha$ and $\overline\beta$ satisfy all the required properties and hence, give a solution to the problem.

Comment: This looks good. Good job. By the way, if you're studying differential geometry, you might find my text, linked in my profile, interesting or useful.

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh, thank you very much! I'll surely look at your text. Thanks again!